# How to optimize objective function that contains the “k-largest” operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, order-theory, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{x,y} f(x*A+y*B)$$
$$s.t  ~~~ \{x,y\} \geq 0$$
$$~~~~~~~ x+y=1$$

in which, $A,B$ are square matrices and $x,y$ are scalars.
The function $f(A)=\sum s_i$, and $s_i$ means sum of $k$ largest entries in the $i$th row of $A$.

For example if 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
5 & 1 & 7\\
3 & 4 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$, then $f(A)$ for $k=2$ would be $(2+3)+(5+7)+(4+3)=24$

If i could calculate the derivatives of $f$ respect to $(x,y)$ then the problem would be solved easily.
Also i know that one way to deal with "$max(a)$" in an objective is to add a stack variable $t$ to the objective and adding $a \leq t$ to the constraints. But i couldn't find the above problem that straightforward.

In order to compare the optimality of the solution, I solve the above problem using the Matlab general solver, but i need to know how can i optimize it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum of the $k$ largest elements in a vector is a convex function and is linear programming representable if you use the operator in a convex setting (which you do as you minimize a sum of those operators)

The epigraph representation (with $s$ representing the value) of the sum of the $k$ largest elements of a vector $x$ can be constructed by first introducing an auxiliary variable $z$ of same dimension as $x$, and an additional scalar $q$ and the linear constraints

$$     s\geq kq+\sum z,~z \geq 0, ~z-x+q \geq  0$$

In your case, you simply want to apply this to every column of your matrix and sum up the epigraph variables $s_i$.

Here is an example in the optimization language YALMIP which overloads this operator (disclaimer, MATLAB Toolbox developed by me)

```
A = randn(3);
B = randn(3);
sdpvar x y
C = x*A + y*B;
Objective = sumk(C(:,1),2)+sumk(C(:,2),2)+sumk(C(:,3),2);
Constraints = [x >= 0, y >= 0, x + y == 1];
optimize(Constraints,Objective)
```

Comment: Very nice!! (+1) This is way more efficient than my solution. Thanks! I learned something new.

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution. I tried the epigraph representation and it works, but i couldn't figure out why, and also couldn't get the logic behind those additional constraints involving the auxiliary variables $z,q$?

Comment: If i try $sumk(C(:,1),2) - sumk(C(:,2),2)$ it fails! Also i tried it with the epigraph representation. Is it because the "-" makes it a non-convex problem?!

Comment: sumk is convex, hence -sumk is concave and thus the difference is not convex.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg correct, but we can use the epigraph representation (in terms of $\vec{s}$) and modifying the sign of inequalities for the 2nd element of $\vec{s}$ which has a negative coefficient. Then the objective would be $[1,-1] * [s_1, s_2]^T$ which is should be convex in the LP settings. It converges this way, but not sure how optimal is the solution.

Comment: What are you saying? If $s_1$ and $s_2$ are convex, then $s_1-s_2$  is nonconvex.

Comment: and you cannot just randomly flip the sign in an epigraph representation (and thus use an hypograph representation) when modelling an operator. That leads to a model of something completely different, most likely nonsense.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Ok! You are right. Then i wonder if there is any way to **maximize** the $k$ largest elements in a vector using convex programming?

Comment: No, impossible. You can formulate it as a MILP though

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. I will give you a reformulation, of a more general problem, which you could solve on the computer.

Consider the problem

$$\min g(x)=f(x_1A_1+ x_2A_2+\ldots + x_n A_n),$$

$$s.t\; x_j\geq 0,\;\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=1.$$ Here $A_l=(a_{ij}^l)\in \Bbb R^{m\times m}$ for $l=1,\ldots,n,$ and $f(A)$ is the summ of the $k$ greatest terms in each row of $A$. In order to simplify notation, for $i,j\in \{1,\ldots,m \},$ define the vector $$c_{ij}=(a_{ij}^1,\ldots,a_{ij}^n )^T.$$ With this notation, we have that the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix $A(x)=x_1A_1+ x_2A_2+\ldots + x_n A_n$ is just $c_{ij}^Tx.$ Now, a reformulation of the problem is

$$\min \sum_{i=1}^m s_i,$$
$$s.t \; x\geq 0,\;\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=1,$$
$$\sum_{t=1}^k c_{ij_t}^Tx\leq s_i, \;\forall \;i\in \{1,\ldots, m\},\;(j_1,\ldots,j_k)\subseteq \{1,\ldots,m\}. $$

As you see, there are approximately $m \times C_k^m$ constraints in the reformulation, which makes the problem hard to solve. But hey, it is a difficult problem!! Hope this helps