# Linear constraint expressing the sum of the $k$ largest elements

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, order-statistics

I have an optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
    \quad \max\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}& f(x)\\
    \text{subject to} \quad & 0\leq x_i \leq 1 &\forall i\in\{1, \dots, n\}\\
    & x\in D
\end{align*}
where $D$ is the set of all vectors $x\in [0,1]^n$ such that the sum of the largest $k$ components of $x$ is less than or equal to $m$, where $1 \leq k \leq n$ and $m \geq 0$ are fixed numbers.

My question is: Can I translate the constraint $x\in D$ into a set of linear constraints for this optimization problem? Furthermore, can the set of resulting linear constraints be polynomial in $n$?

I looked at [Minimize the sum of $r$-largest entries with constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272774/minimize-the-sum-of-r-largest-entries-with-constraints)
and
[How to optimize objective function that contains the “k-largest” operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429850/how-to-optimize-objective-function-that-contains-the-k-largest-operator) ,
but I don't know if I can translate the constraint $x\in D$ into a set of linear constraints on its own (i.e. without translating it into an optimization problem of its own), which is what I would want because I already have an objective function $f(x)$ that I want to optimize.

Comment: If the sum of the $k$-largest components needs to be $\leq m$, then also summing any $k$-components of $x$ needs to be $\leq m.$
So define your matrix $A$ with $n$ columns, where each row contains exactly $k$ ones, and each row corresponds to a permutation of the $k$-ones in the $n$ columns.

This might be a bit of an overkill because we´re creating a huge matrix, but at least it`s linear:

$$Ax\preceq m$$

Comment: I should have specified that I am looking to have a polynomial number of constraints, whereas your method would have a factorial number of constraints. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $x_i$ is among the largest $k$.  Let continuous decision variable $z_i\in[0,1]$ represent the product $x_i y_i$.  Let $w$ represent the $k$th largest value of $x_i$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &= k \\
\sum_i z_i &\le m \\
z_i &\le y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
-(1-y_i) \le z_i - x_i &\le 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
x - w &\le y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \\
w - x &\le 1-y_i &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to make it an LP (not have $y_i$ be a binary decision variable)?

Comment: Yes, you can use the epigraph formulation in the second link you provided. Just replace the variable $s$ with the constant $m$.  It works because you want the sum of the $k$ largest to be $\le m$.  If you instead wanted $\ge m$, you would need binary variables as in my formulation.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!